# 403 forbidden for /var/www after editing apache.conf

Tags: apache

Code:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

After editing some code in /var/www thinking I'd fix a small error where it denied access from everyone except me, somehow I screwed it up and I'm not firmiliar with this file at all. Now, everyone who visits any dir on my website gets 403 forbidden including myself.

Comment: check error status http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Answer (score 0):

is better to know that OS using often resolved by changing the permissions on the folder

for example server Ubuntu

sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/youfile

that's it

Regards

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu, and the command didn't work. Still getting 403 forbidden, are you sure it isn't a issue on the Apache2.conf?